# objective-c UIPageViewController and PageControls

Tags: objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, pagecontrol

I'm creating UIPageViewController and overriding these functions:

```
 - (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
 - (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
```

and it creates a PageControl here.

How can i change the style of PageContol? (default is white, but i need dark)

Comment: UIPageViewController conforms to the UIAppearance protocol and you may be able to do some color customizations this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the UIPageControl class reference (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html), you can find two properties that will be of your interest: *pageIndicatorTintColor* and *currentPageIndicatorTintColor*.

Change those two properties of you UIPageControl instance with UIColor you want, e.g. [UIColor blackColor] for dark color, etc.